# How can I correctly place a red oval in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, position

[Where should the red oval be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wllnH.png)

Hello, my question is how can I get the red oval in the picture above to the position marked below? Does anyone know? I thank you in advance.

This is my code:

> ```
> return Scaffold(
>   backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
>   body: Stack(
>     children: <Widget>[
>       Container(
>         child: Align(
>           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
>         ),
>         width: 436.0,
>         height: 207.0,
>         decoration: BoxDecoration(
>           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29.0),
>           image: DecorationImage(
>             image: const AssetImage('assets/images/vorlage.png'),
>             fit: BoxFit.cover,
>           ),
>         ),
>       ),
>       Container(
>         child: Align(
>           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
>         ),
>         width: 265.0,
>         height: 20.0,
>         decoration: BoxDecoration(
>           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
>           color: const Color(0xffff0000),
>         ),
>       ),
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to look into painting a Canvas.  It's fairly well developed, and quite a bit of tutorial information on it (even how to animate things!).  Everything is a widget, but some of those widgets are RenderObjects. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to red oval to always be fixed at a position in it's parent widget, you can use Positioned widget to fix the distance from top, then use Center to place it in the middle. You will have to tweak the top value (I put 300 arbitrarily).

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        ),
        width: 436.0,
        height: 207.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29.0),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: const AssetImage('assets/images/vorlage.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 300 // <----tweak this till it's where you want it (distance from top)
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
            width: 265.0,
            height: 20.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
              color: const Color(0xffff0000),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```